# In Intellij how to set javascript to es6 on a per-file basis?

Tags: intellij-idea

I know how to set Javascript Language Version to ES6 for the whole project (Language & Frameworks -> Javascript...etc).

But how to set it only for one file ? I have a big ES5 project and would like to start using ES6 one file at a time without having Intellij complaining on all files.

Is there some kind of annotation like "/** ES6 **/" i could use ? Or is it in a panel inside preferences ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I faced the same question and fortunately this feature was released recently (since IntelliJ 2017.3).

From [official website](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/09/webstorm-2017-3-eap-173-2463/#multiple-js-versions):

> The easiest option is to enable the highest language version for the whole project in **Preferences** | **Languages and Frameworks** | **JavaScript**. For example, if you use ES5.1 and JSX, enable JSX (since it’s a superset of ES5.1 and ES6).
>
> Now you can also configure different JavaScript language versions for different folders. Click the `…` button next to the drop-down with the version, then select a folder and the language version used for its files. The version specified on the main settings page will be applied by default for all other JavaScript files in the project.

[image]
<sub>(source: [cloudfront.net](https://d3nmt5vlzunoa1.cloudfront.net/webstorm/files/2017/09/js-versions.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 2):

No, JavaScript Language level can only be set per-project, there is no way to specify version for individual file/folder. If you miss a possibility to have several language versions in your project, please vote for [WEB-12666](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-12666). For now I can suggest choosing `ECMAScript 6` version - it covers both ES6 and ES5 features.